# Attach callback to multiple jquery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have multiple deferred objects. I need to attach handlers to be fired once per deferred object.

I know that I can use

```
$.when.apply($, my_array);
```

but as I understand it, done will only be fired once all deferred objects are resolved.

I need done to be fired every time an object is resolved. I can probably use a loop but I would like to know if there is something like on the lines of the above line using $.when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to use a loop; there's no syntax sugar for handing each promise individually.

```
function doneCallback() {
  // your common callback
}

$.each(my_array, function(my_deferred) {
    my_deferred.done(doneCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're trying to do but it sounds like what you need to do is create a master deferred object then pipe the array of deferred objects to it. Add your handlers to the objects in the array using `.always()` which fires whether the deferred fails or succeeds. When all of the child deferred objects are resolved the master deferred `.done()` will fire.

Also $.when() can handle arrays of deferred objects so you could try `$.when(my_array).always(function()...)`

Comment: I think OP wants the `done` handler to fire for _each_ promise. (eg 3 promises results in 3 `done` calls.)

Comment: In that case I think he can do my_array.on('done', function(){});

Comment: @Mathletics is right.Is on('done') officially supported. I couldn't find any info on it.